# Selenium Python - different data each row but get same data always

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm working on a project with selenium python. Most of the code is running well. I have a problem with data rows, same tags each row, but different information in the tags. I can read out the content. Now the difficult part: I get 100 rows for each page. The Website has no limit in page number. Each row has the same session and different element, if I print the data to the console. For example three lines:
*Code*

```
for data in dataRows:
    print(data)
```

*Output*

```
<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="4d1e8794-7f0e-4d81-b69c-9a57cbdfbf06", element="dea59981-3e6e-48fb-ac25-54fed3eee649")>
<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="4d1e8794-7f0e-4d81-b69c-9a57cbdfbf06", element="8b212678-b7f1-45fe-8bbe-4f68ef973b48")>
<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="4d1e8794-7f0e-4d81-b69c-9a57cbdfbf06", element="62b5a1bf-3bb5-46a6-bf31-6e9de878710d")>
```

If I search in a node  xPath for a specific information

```
#collect all rows from table
dataRows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table/div")

#print data of rows
for data in dataRows:
    print(data.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='name']").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
    print(data.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='year']").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
    print(data.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='age']").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

*Note: I used print() instead variables. It's make it more clear hopefully.*


I get the output at console:

```
Tom Hulk
1991
30
Tom Hulk
1991
30
Tom Hulk
1991
30
```

Question: Why give a different element of a session the same data back?


I readed the documentation and other question about selenium, but it didn't give me a clue. Any idea? Did I miss something?

Comment: Your post also not giving any clue, unless you adding the html code of the page or intended elements. Dont add the screenshot no one will write that for you by looking into image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use .// infront of all your xpaths to get the correct values.

Without . the values will pull from the root and always get the first value.